# Enable assertions in Play! development mode

Tags: java, playframework, assertions

I'm want to enable assertions for the Play! JVM. I saw there is some configuration in the application.conf, but I'd no success by guessing how this may work. So, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean support for the "assert" language feature, it seems to be as simple as:

```
play run -ea
```

Comment: How about running the tests with java asserts enabled?

I tried play test -ea, but no joy...